# How can I play and manipulate .wav files using Java?

Tags: java, javasound

I'm looking for a small library to play, merge and change pitch for .wav files.

I've tried JASS, beads, something from anyexample.com, basic javax.sound examples, Sonia Sound Library etc.

Can anyone help me? I just need change pitch, merge and play wav files in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [Java Media Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework)? Even though it has its limitations, it may be an option. In addition, the wikipedia article (linked above) has a listing of alternatives - maybe one of them does the trick for you.